# A better way to get a distance?

Tags: android, time

I am currently writing a program that tries to measure the speed of a person walking, via GPS.

```
   if (OldLocation != null) {
        OldLocation = NewLocation;
        NewLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } else {
        OldLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        try {Thread.sleep(mInterval);} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        NewLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
    float distance = OldLocation.distanceTo(NewLocation);
    float speed = distance / mInterval;
```

Here, I am currently using Thread.sleep to 'stagger', or delay getting NewLocation after getting the OldLocation.

However, I am using another system with mInterval:

```
Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker,mInterval);
    }
};
```

... to delay the entire sequence of the first. I am unsure if this will actually work in practice.
Can anyone see a fault in this, or a much simpler way to go about it?

Thank you!

Comment: obviously the right way is do not using getLastKnownLocation at all but register for provider updates... `Thread.sleep(mInterval);` on main thread hurts my eyes

Comment: My dear Selvin, I can see from your numerous posts that you do not condone people who have less programming knowledge than you, but if you could refrain from adding condescending language, that would be great.

Comment: In fact, I have done a bit of research, and I cobbled this snippet from various answers inside StackExchange. Though I can see from your...personality that you will not be deterred from your path.

Comment: I do not remeber exactly, search for something with Location-Aware apps on official android's training website ... topic about updates

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: Oh. I was not aware of this. Thank you for your help.